# Socket Connection Security From Flash

Tags: java, flash, security, sockets, actionscript

I have a flash application that connects to java socket server. Some hackers try to imitate messages from an external software like charles, winsock pocket editor. How can I create a secure connection that the server would only accept commands coming from flash?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fundamentally impossible. The best you can do is make attacks more work, but even then it's likely to cause you more work than an adversary.

Even if you were to encrypt the communication, you'd have to ship a key which an adversary could inspect. Possibly the easiest route for an attacker over obfuscated channel would be to alter the running flash program.

(In theory, you could have a trusted platform which wipes on tampering. But that isn't a PC.)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend below site. this site is great site have a many kinds of tutorial with you want that java flash socket connection. but this site is in Japanese, but if you use Google translate to view and there will not be a big problem. of course some Is awkward, but, there will not be a big problem.for 3 years i visited a many kinds of flash, as3.0 tutorial site. i think, this site was the best for me.

[flash(as3.0)-java socket connection tutoral](http://hakuhin.jp/as/xml_socket.html)

Comment: The site you have provided is a broken link :) Also, I think I haven't clarified the situation here. I already have a live application communicating the java socket server. What I need is a limitation that can be defined from the server side (maybe) that the server only accepts calls from the flash client.